# A little-o dilemma or the expectation of the KDE

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, statistics, asymptotics

This question arose out of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/530541/263915) on Cross Validated, but there is no need to click the link since all the necessary details will be summarized here. The level of probability theory and statistics involved in this question is very basic. It is about calculus if anything.

This question assumes the following definition of the little-o if given a function $f(x)$:

$$ f\in o(x) \iff \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0,$$
where $x_0$ is a real number, a complex number or $\pm \infty$.

### Background

Suppose $x_1, ..., x_n$ are independent and identically distributed observations of a random variable $X$ with unknown distribution function $F$ and probability density function $f\in C^m$, for some $m>1$ fixed. Let $k\in C^{m+1}$ be a given fixed function such that
\begin{align}
k&\geq 0, \\
\mathrm{supp} (k)&=[-1,1], \\
\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(u)\mathrm{d}u&=1, \\
\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(u)u^l\mathrm{d}u&=0 \ \text{for all} \ 1\leq l<m \ \text{and}\\
\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(u)u^m\mathrm{d}u&<\infty .
\end{align}
Define the so-called kernel density estimator (KDE) $f_n$ of $f$ by $$f_n(t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{h}k\left(\frac{t-x_i}{h}\right),$$
where $h=h(n)$ is the bandwidth. What is the expectation of $f_n$, i.e.  $\mathbb{E}[f_n(t)]$?.

By linearity of the expectation, identical distribution of $x_1,...,x_n$, the law of the unconscious statistician and the change of variables $u=(t-x)/h$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f_n(t)]&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{h}k\left(\frac{t-x_i}{h}\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{h}k\left(\frac{t-x}{h}\right)\right]\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{h}k\left(\frac{t-x}{h}\right)f(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{h}k(u)f(t-hu)h\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}k(u)f(t-hu)\mathrm{d}u. \tag{1} 
\end{align}
From $f\in C^m$, it follows that $$f(t-hu)=\sum_{l=0}^m \frac{f^{(l)}(t)}{l!} (-hu)^l+o((hu)^m).$$
Then from $(1)$ and linearity of integration,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f_n(t)]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}k(u)\left(\sum_{l=0}^m \frac{f^{(l)}(t)}{l!} (-hu)^l+o((hu)^m)\right)\mathrm{d}u \\
&=\sum_{l=0}^m\int_{\mathbb{R}}k(u)\frac{f^{(l)}(t)(-hu)^l}{l!}\mathrm{d}u+\int_{\mathbb{R}}k(u)o((hu)^m)\mathrm{d}u. \tag{2}
\end{align}
From the given conditions on $k$, the $l=0$ term reads
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(u)f(t)\mathrm{d}u=f(t)\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(u) \mathrm{d}u=f(t).$$
The $1\leq l<m$ terms are
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(u)\frac{f^{(l)}(t)}{l!} (-hu)^l\mathrm{d}u=\frac{f^{(l)}(t)(-h)^l}{l!}\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(u)u^l\mathrm{d}u=0.$$
Finally, the $l=m$ term is $$ \frac{f^{(m)}(t)(-h)^m}{m!}\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(u)u^m\mathrm{d}u<\infty.$$
According to the above linked answer, it holds that $o((hu)^m) = u^m o(h^m)$ and thus the remainder term in $(2)$ is
\begin{equation}
\int_\mathbb{R} k(u) o((hu)^m)\mathrm{d}u = o(h^m)\int_\mathbb{R} k(u) u^m\mathrm{d}u = o(h^m).
\end{equation}

### Question

Why does $o((hu)^m) = u^m o(h^m)$ hold? According to the Taylor expansion and the given definition of little-o, $o((hu)^m)$ means all functions $f$ that satisfy $\lim_{hu\to 0} \frac{f(hu)}{(hu)^m} = 0$. One can pull out factors from the little-o, i.e. $o((hu)^m)=huo((hu)^{m-1})$, but $o((hu)^m) = u^m o(h^m)$ suggests that the variable which the limit in the definition of little-o is taken with respect to has changed.

Comment: I know this is not the main point of your post, but looks as if $(-hu)^l$ was dropped in $(2)$. It looks as if it reappears in later equations.

Comment: @robjohn You are right, thanks! Fixed.

Comment: When defining the KDE, you mention an $f$, which earlier is declared to be $C^m$, but then it is never associated with anything. How does $f$ relate to the KDE?

Comment: @robjohn The KDE estimates $f$, the probability density function of $X$. I guess the only thing that is known about $f$ is that it is in $C^m$. Hence it has no relation to the KDE.

Comment: Okay. I was just wondering because the $f_n$ were said to be the KDE of $f$, I thought they might be related.

Comment: Related; [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/543955).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are looking at asymptotics near $0$
$$
o\!\left(x^m\right)=\left\{f:\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^m}=0\right\}\tag1
$$
As with many things, the nomenclature is not perfect. For example, the scope of the $x$ inside the braces contained there; it is *not* the same $x$ appearing outside the braces. Thus, we don't interpret
$$
o\!\left(x^m\right)=\left\{f:\lim_{x^m\to0}\frac{f\!\left(x^m\right)}{x^m}=0\right\}\tag2
$$
This is because the independent variable is $x$, not $x^m$.

When we see $o\!\left((hu)^m\right)$, we need to determine the independent variable(s) from context. In the question, the integration is with respect to $u$, so the independent variable might appear to be $u$. However, the article is looking at letting $h\to0$ in the estimate, while $u$ is integrated over $\mathbb{R}$, so
$$
o\!\left((hu)^m\right)=\left\{f:\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(u,h)}{(hu)^m}=0\right\}\tag3
$$
We might also write it as $u^mo\!\left(h^m\right)$, but it could also be written as $(hu)^mo(1)$ if we understand that $h\to0$ is the independent variable.

---

**Clarification**

As seen in $(3)$ above, by writing $o\!\left((hu)^m\right)$ as a class, we are confounding two uses of little-o: one as a class of functions and another as a function. This is a prelude to confusion.

The class $o\!\left(x^m\right)$ defined in $(1)$ is a standard class of functions used in asymptotic analysis.

However, as used in the question, $o\!\left((hu)^m\right)$ means $f(hu)$ where $f(x)\in o\!\left(x^m\right)$. Then, we can see more easily why it is claimed that $o\!\left((hu)^m\right)=u^mo\!\left(h^m\right)$:
$$
\underbrace{f(hu)}_{o\left((hu)^m\right)}=u^m\underbrace{g(h)}_{o\left(h^m\right)}\tag4
$$
where $g(x)\in o\!\left(x^m\right)$.

That is, $o\!\left((hu)^m\right)=u^mo\!\left(h^m\right)$ is a statement about functions, not about classes.

Comment: By the way, in your third equation, why is $f$ also a function of $x$ (presumably $u$)? This does not seem to be consistent with your first equation. I would have assumed $$o\!\left((hu)^m\right)=\left\{f:\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{(hu)^m}=0\right\},$$ since $u$ is a function of $h$, right?

Comment: If $f$ were not a function of $u$, too, then, the $u$ would just be a constant, and then $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{(hu)^m}=0$ would be the same as $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h^m}=0$, so why mention $u$ at all? $u$ is not a function of $h$. They are both arguments of $f$, but $u$ is bound by the integral, whereas $h$ is not. This means that $u$ does not extend outside the integral.

Comment: In equation 4, is it not $f(hu)=u^{m+1}g(h,u)$? If $f(x)\in o(x^m)$, one can pull out at most a factor $(hu)^{m+1}$ from $f(hu)$.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{x^m}{\log(x)}\in o\!\left(x^m\right)$; however, you cannot pull out a factor of $(hu)^{m+1}$ from $f(hu)$. That is, $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(hu)}{(hu)^{m+1}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{hu\log(hu)}=\infty$$

Comment: In equation 4, for $f(x)=x^{m+1}$, $g(h)=uh^{m+1}$. So $g$ is possibly a function of $h$ and $u$. I'd also claim it is only in $o(h^m)$ for finite $u$.